# SQL How can I order the data using distinct?

Tags: sql

I have the following Table 'tbl1'.

declare @tbl1 table ( col1 varchar(32))

```
insert into @tbl1
values    ( 'C1' )
        , ( 'B1' )
        , ( 'X1' )
        , ( 'A1' )
        , ( 'B1' )
        , ( 'C1' )
        , ( 'B1' )
        , ( 'A1' )
        , ( 'X1' )
        , ( 'C1' )
        , ( 'D1' )
```

I tried the following query

```
select distinct col1
from @tbl1
order by col1
```

The output should come in the following order, and remove all the duplicate value

```
C1
B1
X1
A1
D1
```

Comment: If you want to be sure on the order of the data, you will always have to explicitly specify an `ORDER BY` clause. Failing to do that can lead to unexpected sorting, even if (at first glance) nothing changed.

Comment: Apart from that, the sample data does not seem ordered at all. It's probably ordered by a column you're not showing us?

Comment: With RDBMS, the order is not set unless you add an order (@SchmitzIT). This is just a set of unordered rows. Without an order, there is no way to make sure it will never change when you execute the same query.

Comment: It seems you want to sort a column by no existing ordering (i.e. no numeric ordering, nor natural or alphabetical ordering); the only way to get the ordering you want is to add an 'ordering' column and explicitly set the order of each row with numbers.

Comment: Tables are unordered bags of rows. There's no exposed "inherent" order to a table. So if you want to maintain the same ordering as was applied in your `VALUES` on your `INSERT`, that information was lost during the insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the order for your items, as others have noted.

Also you need a subquery and grouping to be able to sort over the minimal order column.

```
declare @source table (id int not null identity primary key, name nvarchar(3));
insert into @source
values    ( 'C1' )
        , ( 'B1' )
        , ( 'X1' )
        , ( 'A1' )
        , ( 'B1' )
        , ( 'C1' )
        , ( 'B1' )
        , ( 'A1' )
        , ( 'X1' )
        , ( 'C1' )
        , ( 'D1' )
;
with grouped as
(
    select min(id) as minId, name from @source
    group by name
)
select name from grouped order by minId;
```

The query could be rewritten without CTE:

```
select grouped.name from
    (select min(id) as minId, name from @source group by name) grouped
order by grouped.minId;
```

This yields exactly the result you requested.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat what others have pointed out in comments: if you specify no `ORDER`, then the order of results is not guaranteed. The fact that you get your results in a certain order currently should be treated as coincidental. **If you want a certain ordering in your results, *you have to be explicit about it***!

As an interesting note, in my experience this is especially important if you're doing a `DISTINCT` in your query, because depending on the statistics for your tables, the engine may or may not decide that ordering the data to execute the `DISTINCT` is in fact the best possible plan.

Given that you mention a *very* explicit ordering requirement...

> The output should come in the following order, and remove all the duplicate value
>
> ```
> C1
> B1
> X1
> A1
> D1
> ```

...you should make that explicit in your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
        *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN Col1 = 'C1' THEN 0
            WHEN Col1 = 'B1' THEN 1
            WHEN Col1 = 'X1' THEN 2
            WHEN Col1 = 'A1' THEN 3
            WHEN Col1 = 'D1' THEN 4
            ELSE 5
        END AS SortColumn
FROM tbl1
ORDER BY SortColumn
```

Comment: col1 value is not hard coded value, that is the dynamic value it will change and new value will insert

Comment: Could be. But my answer is to the question as you posted it. If your scenario is different from what you've currently posted, please edit your question and include all the relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

(extension of Jeroen response)

If your "key" values are dynamic, you normally should have a separate table with the order of the keys...

```
declare @sort table (id varchar(10), ord int)

insert into @sort
values ( 'C1', 1 )
     , ( 'X1', 2 )
     , ( 'B1', 3 )
     , ( 'A1', 4 )
     , ( 'D1', 5 )
```

then you join/subquery on that table to calculate the `SortColumn`

```
-- join
SELECT DISTINCT 
        t.*, 
        s.ord SortColumn
FROM @tbl1 t
LEFT JOIN @sort s ON S.id = t.col1
ORDER BY SortColumn

-- subquery
SELECT DISTINCT 
        t.*, 
        (SELECT s.ord FROM @sort s WHERE s.id = t.col1) SortColumn
FROM @tbl1 t
ORDER BY SortColumn
```

Answer (score -1):

```
declare @tbl1 table ( col1 varchar(32))

insert into @tbl1
values    ( 'Basic Salary' )
        , ( 'HRA' )
        , ( 'OtherAllowance' )
        , ( 'PF' )
        , ( 'Basic Salary' )
        , ( 'HRA' )
        , ( 'Other Allowance' )
        , ( 'PF' )
        , ( 'ESIC' )
        , ( 'Basic Salary' )
        , ( 'HRA' )
        , ( 'Other Allowance' )
        , ( 'PF' )
        , ( 'Basic Salary' )

select distinct col1
from @tbl1
order by col1
```

Comment: This also sort by the name.